# UISearchDisplayController disable clearing text on cancel

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to use a UISearchDisplay controller as the navigation bar in my web browser application. However, when the user activates the search bar and decides to cancel inputting text, whether it be by pressing the dimmed background or the cancel button, the UISearchBar's text is cleared. I've tried replacing the blank text with the current url from the UIWebView, but it doesn't seem like the appropriate way. It displays the UITableView over the web view, even though the search bar is not focused.

My question is, is there a way to prevent the text from being cleared when I cancel inputting text into the search bar. Mobile Safari does this, but I'm not sure how to go about it, exactly. I'm using delegate methods to detect if the text is blank after editing has finished, I know it's not right. I've looked around the documentation but nothing seems to stand out.

I can post code, although it's rather trivial.

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    if ([urlSearchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:_webMain.request.URL.absoluteString]) {
        [urlSearchController.searchBar setText:_webMain.request.URL.absoluteString];
        [urlSearchController.searchResultsTableView setHidden:YES];
    }

}
```

`searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch` was used because it is called when the user presses cancel and when they tap the grey overlay. The only problems are that setting the text makes the table view appear and that the textfield flashes blank before being repopulated.

Comment: Did you implement the UISearchBar delegate: searchBarCancelButtonClicked? You could keep the text entered in a NSString property and when the user cancels, re-populate the UISearchBar text maybe?

Comment: post your code from all your `UISearchBarDelegate` methods that you have implemented and also any other method that is using the `UISearchBar` object.